# What Are The Causes of Laravel 5.5 "MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

Tags: php, laravel

<strike>Before you down-vote me for posting another question about this error, or mark this as duplicate or anything, my question is a bit different</strike>

These are my known causes for this error:

- form and route mismatch, eg: form uses `POST`, route uses `GET`
- CSRF token mismatch / missing: no `csrf` token in meta or in form field

I have checked both of those causes:

- have ensured form and route matches
- have tried to disable `csrf` validation by commenting `csrf` validation middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`, but still got this error (is this correct method?)

Basically, those two are what I know, and what I found when searching here.

So my question is:

## **Beside those 2 causes, is there any other condition that can result in this error?**

In case you want to see my code:

#### routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/export', [
    'as' => 'export.csv',
    'uses' => 'ToolsController@export'
]);
```

#### html form

```
    <form class="form-inline" action="{{ route('export.csv') }}" id="csv_export" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="site_maps">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ request('id') }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Export to CSV</button>
    </form>
```

#### app/Http/Controllers/ToolsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ToolsController extends Controller
{
    public function export(Request $request)
    {
         // some function
    }
}
```

#### Additional Detail:

There is an `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie set, have tried to delete it on browser, but it shows up again.

### update

#### request header

```
POST /export HTTP/1.1
Host: somehost.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 68
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://somehost.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Save-Data: on
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://somehost.com/map/47
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id-ID;q=0.8,id;q=0.7
Cookie: sso_token_33=--some-key--; XSRF-TOKEN=--some-token--; somehost_session=--some-cookie--
```

#### form data

```
_token=--some-other-token--&type=site_maps&id=47
```

<strike>no route grouping</strike>

### update

i have a weird case, as you can see in image below, the browser is correctly send a POST request, but laravel seems to see it as GET request,
is there any Apache settings that can cause this behaviour?

[image: post vs get]

route list:

```
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI            | Name           | Action                                          | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | POST     | export         | export.csv     | App\Http\Controllers\ToolsController@export     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | map/{id}       | pages.show     | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@show       | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | tree           | pages.tree     | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@tree       | web          |
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Remove dot from route name just try exportcsv.

Comment: no effect, and the link that generated from it is already correct

Comment: Does there any other route is defined with the same path or name? Can check it by using "php artisan route:list".

Comment: What about using a more fluent way to define the route:
`Route::post('/export', 'ToolsController@export')->name('export.csv');`

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ---- add that in your html form .

Comment: @MinarMnr There isn't any file field in the form, so the enctype attribute is not necessary.

Comment: @Kenny no other route with same name, but let me double check, --confirmed no double

Comment: @nakov no effect, still got this error

Comment: @am05mhz What server do you use? Have you tried defining a new route, method type `get` and try if that will get invoked as it should? As I can't find anything wrong in your code. Try to restart the application server.

Comment: Is your controller folder name Constrollers? Check if you are using proper namespace in controller.

Comment: @KamalPaliwal, lol sorry, that was typo when typing question

Comment: @am05mhz Is controllers namespace written correctly? what's it?

Comment: move your route codes to first line then test

Comment: @KamalPaliwal have updated the question with correct namespace

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad it is already the first route

Comment: run php artisan route:list to check your route registration

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad only single route to `export`

Comment: send me the output

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad already in the post above, at the very bottom

Comment: Do you have any Apache redirect/rewrite rules, e.g. for adding/removing www or https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is **only** thrown when the method doesn't match the route definition. That means all of these conditions are true:

- The request HTTP verb (GET, POST, etc.) is not in the list of allowed methods as defined by the matched route
- *and* a [`_method`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-method-field) form field was not sent
- *and* an `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header was not sent
- *and* the method was not `OPTIONS`

Some route definitions allow multiple methods. For example, `Route::get()` defines GET and HEAD as acceptable.

#### Potential Causes

The error is actually clear (the request used the wrong method), but the cause is sometimes more subtle. Starting from most obvious to least obvious, here are common causes:

- Sending a GET request to a route defined as `Route::post()`
- Defining a DELETE, PATCH, etc. route and forgetting the `_method` field in an HTML form
- Requesting the wrong route (typo, copy/paste error) - check the network tab of your developer tools and compare the *Request Headers* `:path` and `:method` with the URI and Method columns of `php artisan route:list`
- Defining the route inside a `Route::group()` might have added a url prefix such as `api/` or `admin/` - this will be visible with `route:list`
- Defining the routes in the wrong order, e.g. `users/active` needs to be defined before `users/{user}` otherwise the `{user}` route variable will match `'active'`

If you still don't see a problem, try tinker against the path you *copy from the Request Headers in the network tab* of your developer tools:

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> $uri = '/your/requested/path'
>>> $method = 'POST'
>>> app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create($uri, $method))
=> Illuminate\Routing\Route {#191
 +uri: "...",
    ...
```

If everything *still* looks correct, it might be time to start examining your Apache/Nginx/IIS configurations, specifically looking for redirect/rewrite situations such as adding/removing subdomains (like www) or https.

Or, if that threw the same exception then try without the $method and carefully examine the response:

```
>>> app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create($uri))
```

---

A problem with the csrf token would *not* cause this error. Instead, that would throw a different exception such as `TokenMismatchException`, or in some cases maybe an authorization error. Likewise, cookie issues should not cause an error like this.

Since this is a Laravel/Symfony exception, it *should* rule out an IIS/Apache/Nginx problem (unless a rewrite rule is intercepting the request). For example, IIS has some verbs disabled by default (PUT, DELETE, etc.) but instead would display an IIS 405 error page in that case.

Comment: this adds a few points to check, and nice trick with tinker, will check later in office

Comment: you are right that it must be the route mismatch, have found the prove of route mismatch, but have not found the cause